# How to create a distribution minus some packages in maven?

Tags: java, maven-2

I have a maven project with the following packages (for illustration only):

Root: `src/main/java`

- `/com/foo`
- `/com/foo/api`
- `/com/foo/impl`

Now I want to create a jar which includes only code in `/com/foo/api` and `/com/foo/impl`.

How does one hack pom.xml to do this ? Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, use the `<includes>` tag on the jar plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <includes>
      <include>/com/foo/api/*</include>
      <include>/com/foo/impl/*</include>
    </includes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

There's a section on including/excluding in the [usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html) section of the plugin doc.

Comment: Thanks. But I used **/foo/api/* and **/foo/impl/* as the include fileset and it works.